# javascript toISOString return incorrect date issue

Tags: javascript

The toISOString method return incorrect date.

```
 // Input 
    var a = new Date("June 08, 2018");
    a.toISOString().slice(0, 10);

 // Output
    "2018-06-07"

// Expected output
   "2018-06-08"
```

Answer (score 9):

Use `Z` at the end of your date value. This will ignore the ISO timezone conversion and it will give you the value based on your local time.

```js
var a = new Date("June 08, 2018 Z");
var res = a.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: @anonymous you can accept the answer if it was helpful to you :)

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer.

Comment: This doesn't work for Firefox.